# DotNetOpenAuth - Message signature was incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

There is [already a StackOverflow post that has addressed this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505565/dotnetopenauth-message-signature-was-incorrect). However, it couldn't help me.

So, I have written an OpenID login implementation using DotNetOpenAuth and I keep on getting "Message signature was incorrect".

The funny thing is that this is happening from a PC I have at my home. At my work I'm **not** getting this error and it is working ok.

I've tried to add in the web.config

```
<trust level="Full" />
<httpRuntime maxQueryStringLength="20000" />
```

Also, I've added the null parameter while instantiating the OpenIdRelyingParty

`new OpenIdRelyingParty(null)`

Lastly, I've opened the 443 port in the router and PC.

The key factor is that this is not working from the PC I have at home. However, it is working from the PC I have at work. Both have the same exact code.

Comment: Are you testing it with the same data at home as you are at work?

Comment: Yes, with the same account. Can there be a port that is blocking this maybe? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this topic, but have you already got a solution? I have the same problem: I use Google and Yahoo. Both work fine on the development server of Visual Studio, but on the live server only Yahoo works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make a request to an OAuth provider, the framework generates a signature. This signature is a hash of different values, including the URL that you are requesting. The provider then does the same and performs a comparison. If the hash that the provider builds is not the same as the one you've provided via the oauth_signature query string parameter, the request is not considered valid, and you get this error.

I ran into a similar issue when my client application was signing an URL that was something along the lines of api.foo.com/oauth. The server had an URL rewriter that rewrote the URL to foo.com/api/oauth *before* the provider had a chance to process anything. Since the client URL and the URL that was processed by the provider were different, this caused different signatures, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Check your computer clock.  The time should be correct *as well as the timezone*.

If that doesn't help it, please [activate logging](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Logging-and-debugging) and see if it gives you more details about why the signature is wrong.